# Why doesn't $77=1$? (I'll explain in question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Firstly I believe there is probably a very simple answer here but I don't quite understand.

Let's say we have the equation $77x-x=0$. Obviously this is equal to $76x=0$ so $x=0$. But why doesn't the following also work:

$$77x-x=0$$
$$77x=x$$
$$77=1$$

I'm pretty sure that $77$ does not equal $1$ so can someone please explain to me why the second method does not work. Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned that $x=0$. So how does $77x = x$ imply that $77=1$?

Comment: Well as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the algebra in the second method which gets to $77=1$ so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @Dan Division by zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most common mistake made by beginning algebra students (and on occasion, even by experts when its sufficiently disguised):

> I will divide by sides of the equation by a number!

This is *not a legal operation*! What *is* legal is

> I will divide by sides of the equation by a *nonzero* number!

Passing from $77x = x$ to $77 = 1$ can only be done in the case that $x$ is a *nonzero* number. But you haven't established that, so you can't do it!

What you *can* do is split the problem into two cases: one where $x=0$ and one where $x$ is nonzero. In the *latter* case, you can divide by $x$ to conclude $77=1$.

So, what you can actually conclude here is, given the equation $77x - x = 0$, that

- Either $x=0$ or $77=1$ (or both)

Of course, you had already determined that $x=0$; you could skip all of the above since you know the "$x$ is nonzero" case doesn't happen.

---

Incidentally, if you *were* able to *correctly* deduce $77=1$, the result is known to be a contradiction, and so you would conclude the premise is false: that $77x - x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$77x=x$ implies nothing more nor less than $x (77-1) = 0$, which implies nothing more nor less than $76x=0$, which implies nothing more nor less than "$x = 0$ or $76 = 0$". From the fact that "$x=0$ or $76=0$", you can't deduce that $76=0$ (and hence that $77=1$).

Answer (score 0):

When you have $77x = x$, it seems that your next step was to divide both sides by $x$.

But, dividing both sides by $0$ is problematic; and, indeed, here you have $x = 0$.

In a similar vein, if $x = 0$, then $10x = 0$. Adding $x$ to both sides yields $11x = x$; again, it would be unwise to divide both sides by $x$ and conclude that $11 = 1$. You could continue in this way to "conclude" that any two numbers are equal!

Comment: Ah I see. My problem was that I was seeing $x$ as a variable and not as 0 (as that's the only solution). Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: @Dan Yes, $x$ is a variable in the sense of, you are wondering about the solution set: i.e., the set of $x$ that make your given equation true. So, you must always caveat $x \neq 0$ when dividing both sides by $x$; for example, to solve $2x^2 = x$, observe that this is true when $x=0$. Now suppose $x \neq 0$ and we can divide both sides by $x$ to obtain $2x = 1$ hence $x = 1/2$. So, the solution set is $\{0, 1/2\}$, which is more often found by rewriting the equation as $2x^2 - x = 0$ hence $x(2x-1) = 0$ and using the zero product property to conclude $x=0$ or $2x-1=0$.